# How extracted 10 numbers, from 100 numbers in php

Tags: php, numbers

How extracted 10 numbers, from 100 numbers .
With a different number each time until the matter ends 
in php.
Example:

```
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.11
.
.
7.9.15.19.22.26.31.38.40.60
2.4.13.21.25.34.39.40.42.50
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Wait.. what? What's your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go..

```
<?php 
$array = range(1,100); //create array of element 1,2,3......,100
 shuffle($array); // randomized number without repetition
$chunkOf10 = array_chunk($array, 10);
$i=1;
 foreach($chunkOf10 as $key=>$chunk){ // assign array of ten element from 100 values into     $chunk
 print "Chunk $i is"; print_r($chunk); print '<br/><br/>';
$i++;
}
?>
```

or you can use code below to display random numbers without repetition in square blaket as you want

```
<?php 
$array = range(1,100); //create array of element 1,2,3......,100
 shuffle($array);
 $chunkOf10 = array_chunk($array, 10);
$i=0;
 foreach($chunkOf10 as $key=>$chunk){ // assign array of ten element from 100 values     into   $chunk
  foreach($chunk as $index=>$value){
    print " [ $chunk[$i] ]";
    if($index == 9){ echo '<br/>'; $i=-1;  }
  $i++;
   }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Yes like this 
But I want all estimates 
Not only 10 columns

Comment: What do you mean estimates?

Comment: How columns will need to extract all the numbers without repeating numbers

Comment: yeah, the number are no repeat, look at them closely..

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation

Comment: But how do I order numbers

Answer (score 0):

It's actually simple.

1. You just need to convert whatever number set/input you have into an [`array`](http://php.net/array).
2. Simply [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) that list.
3. And lastly just [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) the wholy randomized array, to break it up into subarrays of 10 elements each.